# Android: sample to show WebView with scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, webview

This should be pretty basic, I just can't find out how.  I have a webView that shows a page to is too long to show all at once.  Right now, it shows the scroll bar, but it doesn't really scroll.  It just kinda wiggles a little bit just enough to let you know it's an active scroll bar.

Hopefully, in the xml layout, as much as possible, I would like to have the page scroll as needed to show the whole page.

my xml layout file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/news_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

onCreate call:

```java
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.news_view);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/index.html");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "kinda moves a little bit"? Please specify more clearly what doesn't work properly.

Comment: Basically, it wiggles a bit to let you know it's an active scroll bar, but that the scroll length is the length of the visable view.

Comment: I tried it out, it looks like the page does not contain enough info for you notice the scrolling. Try loading a page with more content, like www.thinkgeek.com :)

Comment: Whats the initial scale you are using?

Comment: @Donal: Not doing anything about scaling, so the defaults I suppose.

Comment: After testing this out with some different pages, it does seem to scroll most pages.  Unfortunately, the page I need seems to do some funky javascript upon scrolling that seems 'kill' my scroll motions.  More info as I find out...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

did you think about using ScrollView ??

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="86px" 
            android:id="@+id/scrollTxtDescription"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtLieuPromo1" 
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtLieuPromo1">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layoutTxtDescription"
                >

                <WebView android:id="@+id/txtDescription" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried this in a couple of different ways and it always resulted in some xml errors.  What sdk ver is it?

Comment: i've tried this in Android 1.6 and it works , i have my webView in a ScrollView , and it works fine, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

i use the next code and it worked for me (tested on android 2.3 and android 4.2 )

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

code:

```
final WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
        super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        mWebView.requestLayout();
    }

});
mWebView.loadUrl(uri);
```