# how control scroll in webview (Android)

Tags: android, image, webview, scroll

I have an image with low resolution, this image should be shown in a web-view. User can scale the image,  Then i need to replace image with higher resolution after the web-view got the zoom-in event.

I should load image and scroll to same x and y with higher resolution. Any idea? is it possible to do it smoothly?

I have tried this but it is not working

```
 wv.scrollTo(x,y);
```

Comment: Try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238938/how-to-programmatically-scroll-android-webview?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private Runnable mScrollDown = new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_url);
    webview.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
}
};
```

Comment: this might help [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097937/android-sample-to-show-webview-with-scrolling)

Comment: how to load image in the scroll position after the scrolling is finished in webview?