# page is not scrolling when opened in webview from url

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to embbed my pdf in webview of android application.I have done this using below code:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.underconstruction, container,
                false);
        v=rootView;
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        pbLoader = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
           webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
           webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
           webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);      
           webView.setScrollX(1000);
           webView.setScrollY(1000);                                           webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
             webView.loadUrl(
            "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf_url);

        return rootView;

    }
    class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                WebView view, String url) {
            return(false);
        }
    }
```

But my problem is that embedded pdf is not scrolling and if scrolls then not smoothly. I have used this also `wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);` but no use.

Comment: When did a WebView learn to display pdf's? If you retrieve a pdf from google docs and it displays in a webview then you did not get a pdf but html.

Comment: Can you please react on what i said?

Comment: have you tried using scroll view in your layout..??

Comment: yes but that's of no use

Comment: `one thing i have noticed is that scroll is not working in 4.0.4 android version.but it is working perfectly on lollipo and kitkat version `. If so then you should put this information right in the beginning of your post. Otherwise you confuse us.

Comment: @greenapps..calm down..@shivani gupta, try using this  :   webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);      webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true)

Comment: it is scrolling but not scrolling smoothly

Comment: <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <!--your webview layout code-->

</ScrollView>...  try this

Comment: refer this for more details:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097937/android-sample-to-show-webview-with-scrolling

Comment: tried both the ways but still not working

Comment: possible solutions I provided, worked fine for me, nhi ho rha toh its hard luck for u..@shivani gupta

Comment: do one thing, try adding this in your manifest file's <application--> like this:   <application
       ....
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
         >

Comment: i am using htc phone and in it's browser also, pdf is not scrolling smoothly.

Comment: I asked you to add that part in your manifest's application tag:"android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ", did you try it..?? Also do this along with the above method: Right click the project and click "Properties". Then select "Android" from the tree on the left. You can then select the target version on the right.(change it to Android 3.0)

Comment: @shivani gupta is the issue resolved..??

Comment: No. Iswitched to qoppa library but it's giving delvik error while importing qoppa.jar in project