# i want to add linear layout and webview and the screen must be fully scrollable

Tags: android, xml

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width=""
                android:layout_height=""/>
            <WebView
                android:layout_width=""
                android:layout_height=""/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

This like layout I want to achieve where full screen need to be scrollable
Any one suggest better ideas

Comment: No Problem with [`scrollView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6098662/8164071) and you can also use  `NestedScrollview`

Comment: The touch of web view is not properly detected when full scrolling

Comment: i implemented on my project and it was works good for web view touch

Comment: It worked in my code .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:background="#dedede"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:text="LinearLayout" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </WebView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```